# Returning/Outputting Incorrect Value (Leetcode Q)

Tags: python

I'm doing problem [#717 on Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/1-bit-and-2-bit-characters/) and my function seems to be executing the correct 'if/else' branch; however, the return value is incorrect.

Am I missing something here?
(According to my 'print()' statements I should be returning 'True', but the compiler is returning 'False')

```
class Solution:
    def isOneBitCharacter(self, bits: List[int]) -> bool:
        print(bits)
        if (len(bits) == 0):        # 2_bit char last
            print("2_bit char last")
            return False
        elif (len(bits) == 1):      # 1_bit char last
            print("1_bit char last")
            return True
        else:
            if (bits[0] == 1):      # 2_bit char next
                self.isOneBitCharacter(bits[2:])
            else:                   # 1_bit char next
                self.isOneBitCharacter(bits[1:])
```

The failing test input is: [1, 0, 0] returning 'False' when 'True' expected.

Comment: In order for a volunteer here to debug your code, you should post the test input that fails.  Also, as an algorithm hint, I think you only need to look at one bit to make the decision.

Answer (score 0):

When you call isOneBitCharacter with the specified input, it calls itself with a parameter of bits[2:], which is [0].

The recursive call then returns True.  Then the original call returns nothing.

The recursive calls should return the value they get back from the function.  For example:

`return self.isOneBitCharacter(bits[2:])`